# Access VBA To Populate a Table Based on Form Selections

Tags: ms-access, vba

Question for you.

I have a table (let's call it "table 1"), with about 40 different fields in it. I also have a table 2, in which there are three fields: ID, FROM, and TO. (There will be a form front-end attached to this table.) The "FROM" field will have every field from table 1 listed in its 40 cells.

In a perfect world, users will be able to go into that form, and use drop-downs in the "TO" column to select which fields they want populated in a third table, based on the corresponding "FROM" cell next to it.

For example: The user will see "First Name" in the "FROM" column, and decide that he wants to pull that data. So he will use the drop-down in the "TO" next to it, and select "field1". It will then be placed in a third table, in the first column. Then the user looks down a few rows, and sees "SSN" in the "FROM" column. He will want that, so he picks "field2" in the "TO" drop down.

My question is: is this doable? To selectively populate a table, from the data in another table, based on selections made?

Sorry if this wasn't crystal-clear. Let me know if I need to explain anything else.

Comment: Just to clarify... you want to give the user an ability to basically create some view over table? To give the user an option to select and order which columns to display in a final view?

Comment: Entirely. Though it will involve quite a bit of programming. You won't just be able to slap some controls on the screen and expect it to work.

Comment: Exactly. The user will use a form, with drop downs, to select whatever fields they want to pull from the source table, into a "final" table, which they will then view. They might want 5 fields out of the original 40, or 20. And in any order they'd like. 

Yeah... I figured this might not be so easy lol.